# Queing scraping jobs with Bull, Puppeteer, NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, redis, puppeteer

I've recently built a platform on Heroku to host Puppeteer scraping scripts (Express, Node JS). Was going great until the scripts started taking longer and longer to complete. Per Heroku's [documentations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), anything longer then 30 seconds times out the request and it fails.

The way around this is by using Redis server (specifically with the npm module [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)).

I've never heard of queueing before so this is going to be a learning opportunity for myself.

Below is my current code (which works).

I will run you through the process (thoroughly):

1. The server gets the POST request from the client asking it to run this script stored in the database:

```
router.post(
  "/get-data/:id", // route
  ensureAuth, // ensure the person making the request is allowed to make the request in the first place
  fsController.createFile, // creates a .js file where the script will be copied to
  scraperController.getData, // runs the function in the newly created .js file
  csvController.buildCSVAndDeliver // adds that data to a csv file and downloads it
);
```

2. The file is created and the code from the database is copied to it

```
const Script = require("../models/Script");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.createFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const script = await Script.findById({ _id: req.params.id });
    let filename = `./scraper/${script._id}.js`;

    // While loop to check if file exists and to append a digit if it does.
    let counter = 0;
    while (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
      filename = `./scraper/${script._id}${counter}.js`;
      counter++;
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(filename, script.script);
    req.filename = filename;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    fs.unlink(filename);
    res.send(error, "Please Try Again");
    res.redirect('/dashboard')
  }
};
```

3. The scraperController takes that file and executes it

```
const fs = require("fs");

exports.getData = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let scraper = require(`.${req.filename}`);
    const response = await scraper(req.body);
    req.response = response;
    fs.unlinkSync(req.filename);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error, "Please Try Again");
    fs.unlinkSync(req.filename);
  }
};
```

4. Finally, the CSV file is downloaded

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { Parser } = require("json2csv");

exports.buildCSVAndDeliver = async (req, res) => {
  let csvFile = `./csv/${req.params.id}.csv`;

  try {
    const parser = new Parser();
    const csv = parser.parse(req.response);
    fs.writeFileSync(csvFile, csv);
    res.download(csvFile, function () {
      fs.unlinkSync(csvFile);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Now that you know the process, where do I add the queing code? Would it even work with this code structure?

Thank you, and should you need additional information from me, please don't hesitate to ask.